# Problema al crear un archivo zip en php7 usando una consulta mysql

Tags: mysqli, php7

Estoy intentando crear un codigo para crear un archivo zip y lo baje usando una query de mysqli.

He intentado diferentes códigos y obtenido diferentes errores. En la última no tengo mensajes de errores, pero no funciona.

El archivo zip se crea bajo el nombre "Renta_J&J.zip", pero vacío. Y en vez bajarlo, se añade a la misma carpeta donde está el archivo php y vacío.

```
if (isset($_POST['copy_all'])) {
            $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
            $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $filename= "Renta_J&J.zip";

            $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' AND '$ticket_date_to'";
            $search_result = filterTable($query);
            $count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($search_result);



            if ($zip->open($filename,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)){
                    $image_dir = $row['image_dir'];
                    $dir = "../upload/";                    
                    $image_file = $dir.$image_dir;
                    if (file_exists($image_file ) && is_file($image_file )){
                    $zip->addfile($image_file, $image_file );
                }
            }
            $zip->close();

            }else{
                    echo 'Error '.$filename;
            }
}
```

Esta es la sentencia que utilizo para llamar al código php:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="copy_all" value="Copy files"/>
```

No tengo mucha idea, He leído muchos forums y buscado código apropiado con no buenos resultados.

Apreciaría la ayuda!!!

Gracias,

---

Estoy es lo me sale (aparece el array de la query)

````
    array(26) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["ticket_index"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(2) "12" ["ticket_number"]=> string(2) "12" [2]=> string(2) "me" ["ticket_from"]=> string(2) "me" [3]=> string(4) "0.00" ["quantity"]=> string(4) "0.00" [4]=> string(10) "2020-01-14" ["ticket_date"]=> string(10) "2020-01-14" [5]=> string(28) "34-55-tcp_ip_frentea_iso.png" ["image_dir"]=> string(28) "34-55-tcp_ip_frentea_iso.png" [6]=> string(19) "2020-01-22 21:50:35" ["ticket_ts"]=> string(19) "2020-01-22 21:50:35" [7]=> string(1) "1" ["tax"]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "0" ["renta"]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" ["type_insurance"]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" ["type_address"]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" ["descripcion"]=> string(0) "" }

array(26) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["ticket_index"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(3) "543" ["ticket_number"]=> string(3) "543" [2]=> string(2) "31" ["ticket_from"]=> string(2) "31" [3]=> string(4) "0.00" ["quantity"]=> string(4) "0.00" [4]=> string(10) "2020-01-09" ["ticket_date"]=> string(10) "2020-01-09" [5]=> string(13) "10-recibo.PNG" ["image_dir"]=> string(13) "10-recibo.PNG" [6]=> string(19) "2020-01-22 21:51:09" ["ticket_ts"]=> string(19) "2020-01-22 21:51:09" [7]=> string(1) "1" ["tax"]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "0" ["renta"]=> string(1) "0" [9]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" ["type_insurance"]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" ["type_address"]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" ["descripcion"]=> string(0) "" }```
````

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Disculpas no me pensé que estaba escribiendo en el internacional.

Comment: Lo primero sería probar si hay datos realmente: ¿qué muestra un `var_dump($row);`?

Comment: El área de abajo es para respuestas, todo lo que sea relativo a la pregunta lo tienes que poner en ella, pulsando en [edit]. Yo veo que haces `fetch` dos veces de los datos, eso no está bien. Pero depuremos a otro nivel, dentro del bucle muestra lo que se debería estar escribiendo en el archivo poniendo esto dentro del `while`: **`echo $image_file;`**  si dices que se crea vacío, hay que ver si es que no se está creando nada en la variable o si es otro problema.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días @A Cedano,

`echo $image_file;` esto es lo que sale:

```
   /volume1/web/recibos/upload/34-55-tcp_ip_frentea_iso.png/volume1/web/recibos/upload/10-recibo.PNG
```

el problema está en

```
if (file_exists($image_file ) && is_file($image_file )){
                    $zip->addfile($image_file, $image_file );
                    }
```

Por mucha información que veo no veo la solución.